# A thought experiment regarding radiation pressure: A new paradox or another pseudo-paradox?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, reference-frames

Assume a plate with dimensions $L×L$ is located vertically on the ground (normal along $x$ direction) at rest with respect to the lab observer. An electromagnetic wave of $\boldsymbol{E_y}=\boldsymbol{E_0}\cos({\boldsymbol{K.r}-\omega t})$ and $\boldsymbol{B_z}=\boldsymbol{B_0}\cos({\boldsymbol{K.r}-\omega t})$ hits it at the right side of the plate. (The wave moves at $c$ from right to left, that is.) Radiation pressure $p$ on the plate (with the unit of Pascal), from the viewpoint of the lab observer, is thus calculated to be:

$$p=\frac{I}{c}=\frac{\epsilon_0 E_0^2}{2} \space .$$

Now, assume an inertial observer who recedes from the mirror at $v$ towards the right side of the mirror. Using Lorentz transformation for fields, he measures:

$$E_0^\prime=\gamma (E_0+vB_0) \space .$$

For an electromagnetic wave, by substituting $B_0=E_0/c$, we get:

$$E_0^\prime=\gamma E_0 (1+v/c)=\sqrt{\frac{c+v}{c-v}}E_0 \space .$$

The moving observer calculates the pressure as:

$$p^\prime=\frac{I^\prime}{c}=\frac{\epsilon_0 {E^\prime_0}^2}{2}=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}×\frac{c+v}{c-v}E_0^2 \space .$$

This equation shows that not only the radiation pressure is not a Lorentz-invariant, but also it is calculated differently by receding and approaching observers with velocities $v$ and $-v$. However, **pressure**, in its general form (with the unit of Pascal), is a Lorentz-invariant regardless of whether it is a hydraulic pressure or is due to radiation, for example, [see this SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341021/is-pressure-lorentz-invariant?answertab=active#tab-top).

Where is the problem? Is there any relativistic form of radiation pressure of which I may be ignorant?

According to @Dale 's answer and comment, I have designed a thought experiment to better show how radiation pressure culminates in paradox if it is not Lorentz-invariant:

Assume a cylinder located in the middle of a long horizontal piston (box). Two similar monochromatic light sources are also located at the ends of the piston. See the attached figure.

[image: Figure]

From the viewpoint of the lab observer, the cylinder is in balance since the radiation pressure $p$ exerted on both sides of it is similar, and thus it never accelerates. However, an observer, who recedes from the piston at $v$ towards the right side of the piston parallel to its axis, calculates the radiation pressure due to the right light source as: (See the previous calculations.)

$$p^\prime_R=\frac{c+v}{c-v}p \space,$$

whereas the left light source exerts a pressure:

$$p^\prime_L=\frac{c-v}{c+v}p \space.$$

Since $p^\prime_R\not=p^\prime_L$, the cylinder tends to accelerate towards the left side contrary to the viewpoint of the lab observer. (Paradox) Remember that we can use a simple spring, a compressed gas, etc, instead of one of the light sources to produce the same pressure as the other light source from the standpoint of the lab observer, and rethink the paradox.

Comment: I presume equations are missing?

Comment: See https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-17526-4

Comment: The force on the piston should be calculated in its rest frame. Note that force is not a Lorentz invariant.

Comment: @Rob Jeffries The forces can be calculated by multiplying the obtained pressures by the area of the cylinder. The question is whether these forces are compatible with those predicted by Lorentz transformation.

Comment: The forces can be obtained by multiplying the pressures *in the rest frame of the piston* by the area of the cylinder. If you look at the article I pointed you towards you will see there is considerable debate over the transformations of thermodynamic quantites in other frames of reference.

Answer (score 4):

As always, it is a pseudo paradox. Maxwell's equations, the governing equations of classical electromagnetism (EM), are fully relativistic so there can never under any circumstances be a contradiction between classical EM and relativity.

> However, pressure, in its general form (with the unit of Pascal), is a Lorentz-invariant regardless of whether it is a hydraulic pressure or is due to radiation, for example, see this SE question. Where is the problem?

Note, in that link the stress-energy tensor being discussed is that of an ideal gas. For an ideal gas (in units where c=1) in its rest frame the stress-energy tensor of an ideal gas is $$
T_{\mu\nu}=\left(\matrix{\varepsilon  & 0& 0& 0\cr 0& p &0 & 0\cr 0&0& p & 0\cr 0&0&0&p}\right)_{\mu\nu}$$ whereas the stress energy tensor of the EM field is $$
T_{\mu\nu}=\left(\matrix{\varrho & S_x& S_y& S_z\cr S_x& -\sigma_{xx} &-\sigma_{xy} & -\sigma_{xz}\cr S_y &-\sigma_{yx}& -\sigma_{yy} & -\sigma_{yz}\cr S_z& -\sigma_{zx} & -\sigma_{zy} &-\sigma_{zz}}\right)_{\mu\nu}$$ where $\varrho=\frac{1}{2}(E^2+B^2)$ is the energy density of the EM field, $S = E \times B$ is the Poynting vector, and $\sigma_{ij}=E_i E_j + B_i B_j - \varrho \delta_{ij}$ is the Maxwell stress tensor. The EM stress energy tensor does not have the same form as the ideal gas stress energy tensor.

In your case since $E_x=E_z=0 = B_x=B_y$ and $E_y=B_z=E_0$ this simplifies to $$
T_{\mu\nu}=\left(\matrix{E_0^2& E_0^2& 0& 0\cr E_0^2 & E_0^2 &0 & 0\cr 0 &0& 0  & 0\cr 0& 0 & 0 & 0}\right)_{\mu\nu}$$ So the pressure for a plane wave is not like the pressure for an ideal gas. In particular, the pressure in an ideal gas is isotropic, but the pressure in an EM plane wave is not. It has the usual value on a surface normal to the direction of propagation and is 0 on surfaces tangent to the direction of propagation. Also, there is a net momentum flux in the EM plane wave stress energy tensor, but not in an ideal gas (in its rest frame).

In another frame the plane wave EM stress energy tensor is $$T_{\mu'\nu'}=\Lambda_{\mu'}^{\mu}\Lambda_{\nu'}^{\nu} T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1+v}{1-v} \ \left(\matrix{E_0^2& E_0^2& 0& 0\cr E_0^2 & E_0^2 &0 & 0\cr 0 &0& 0  & 0\cr 0& 0 & 0 & 0}\right)_{\mu'\nu'}$$ which varies as expected. The EM radiation pressure is the $T_{xx}$ component which is not invariant.

Edit: added information regarding piston edit to question

Now, for the piston we have the stress-energy tensor on one side as given above. The cylinder is normal to the x direction so its normal can be written $A^{\mu}=(0,1,0,0)$ then the four-force density on that face of the cylinder (assuming complete absorption of the EM field) is $f_{\nu}=T_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu}=(E_0^2,E_0^2,0,0)$.

For the other face of the cylinder the stress energy tensor is $$
T_{\mu\nu}=\left(\matrix{E_0^2& -E_0^2& 0& 0\cr -E_0^2 & E_0^2 &0 & 0\cr 0 &0& 0  & 0\cr 0& 0 & 0 & 0}\right)_{\mu\nu}$$ and the other surface normal is $A^{\mu}=(0,-1,0,0)$ for a four-force density on that face of $f_{\nu}=T_{\mu\nu}A^{\mu}=(E_0^2,-E_0^2,0,0)$

The net four-force density is then simply the sum of those two, which is $(2\ E_0^2,0,0,0)$. Note that there is no net force density, but there is a net power density. This means that the momentum is not changing, but it is increasing in energy and therefore mass (i.e. it is heating up by absorbing the EM radiation and therefore getting more massive).

Now, in the frame where the piston is moving, the four-force density on the first face of the cylinder is given by $f_{\nu'}=\Lambda_{\nu'}^{\nu}f_{\nu}=(\gamma E_0^2 (1+v),\gamma E_0^2 (1+v),0,0)$ and the four-force density on the second face is similarly $f_{\nu'}=(\gamma E_0^2 (1-v),-\gamma E_0^2 (1-v),0,0)$. It is left as an exercise to the interested reader to show that these four-force densities are the same as you get by calculating directly in the moving frame from the stress energy tensor and the surface normal.

Notice, importantly the spacelike component of the four-force density does not cancel out in this frame. In other words, as described in the question the force is indeed different on the two sides of the cylinder, and the net four-force density in the moving frame is given by the sum which is $(2\gamma \ E_0^2, 2\gamma v \ E_0^2,0,0)$ which shows a net increase in energy as in the rest frame and also a net increase in momentum, which is different from the rest frame.

However, because the mass is increasing, the increased momentum may not lead to an increased velocity. The velocity can be calculated as the momentum divided by the energy, which in this case gives $$\frac{2\gamma v \ E_0^2}{2 \gamma \ E_0^2}=v$$ so although there is a non-zero net force and a non-zero change in momentum, the change in momentum is directly proportional to the change in mass so there is no acceleration. Since the cylinder does not accelerate there is no contradiction or paradox between the two frames despite the different forces in the two frames.

In general, in relativity you must consider both the power (change in energy) and the force (change in momentum). If in the rest frame you have no force then there will be no acceleration in any frame. However, if you also have power in that frame then you have a changing mass. A changing mass moving at constant velocity clearly has changing momentum and therefore logically requires a net force to provide that changing momentum, as we see here. This result is a clear and necessary consequence of not accelerating while receiving net power.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100983/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-a-thought-experiment-regarding-radiation-pressure).